# Teamcity Nuget File Conflict

Tags: teamcity, nuget, teamcity-8.0, nuget-package-restore

Is there a way to get Teamcity to interact with the nuget session whilst performing a package restore.

The issue i have is that various files are in a conflicted state and it is prompting to over write, i.e. like this:

```
[update] File Conflict.
[update] File 'App_Start\NinjectWebCommon.cs' already exists in project 'MyProject'. Do you want to overwrite it?
```

Which in turn hangs the build waiting for a response to the prompt, this is obviously not a problem in VS, but i cant find an option in Teamcity to set a default response to prompts like this.

How do people handle this situation?

Comment: How are you executing the package restore? Package Restore should not be running an update and/or installing files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In response to the comment i was using the standard "Nuget Installer" build step, however i had not noticed the "Nuget Update" check box was ticked.  Unchecking that has resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to run the NuGet Update step, you can provide the following command line switch in order to avoid hanging the build:

```
-NonInteractive
```